# c++11 prefered way to limit allowed template argument types

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, c++14

Lets assume, that I have a template function `foo(T)` and I only want to accept integer types for `T`. So the `main.cpp` might look something like this:

```
int main()
{
    int i = 1;
    foo(i); // Should work fine
    foo(&i); // Should not compile
}
```

Now, there are two options to achieve this, that I am aware of:

### 1) Using `static_assert`

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T> void foo(T value) {
    static_assert(std::is_integral<T>::value, "Not integral!");
    // Logic goes here
}
```

This option has the advantage, that I am able to specify an error message.
The disadvantage is that my g++ 4.9.3 does produce a lot of error output for discrepancies among my type `T` and my `// Logic`.

### 2) Using `std::enable_if` in template argument list

```
#include<type_traits>

template<typename T, class = typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value>::type>
void foo(T value) {
        // Logic goes here
}
```

The disadvantage is that the error output produced is not very descriptive of the problem, the advantage is that there is a lot less of it. (The amount of error output could be reduced by combining both approaches.)

### Questions

For completeness, are there any other (good) ways of achieving the same result?

What option should take less compile time?

As far as I know, both approaches are equivalent in what types they allow in `foo()`. Are they?

What I am asking is an expert opinion on "how should this be done in a good code" and what are the conditions of when to use what approach.

Thank you for any input.

Comment: The two are not equivalent. The first one is a hard error, the second one SFINAEs. This has consequences for 1) any other overload of `foo` you may write and 2) any code that wants to inspect whether `foo(&i)` is a valid expression.

Comment: @T.C. huh, what does it mean translated to plain english? I meant equivalent in the sense of what types they allow to be input to `foo()`. ADD: Oh, now I get it... I did not realize this impact, thank you very much for your comment

Comment: 1) For instance, if you have an overload `void foo(double);`, then `foo(1.0f);` won't compile with your first approach but will compile with the second (and call the `double` overload).

Answer (score 1):

In order to illustrate different techniques of achieving your goal, I have changed the example significantly. I hope it still preserves the spirit of your question.

Suppose I have a type for storing rational numbers and I want it to be implicitly convertible from `int`:

```
struct Rational1
{
  int i_;
  Rational1(int i) : i_(i) {}
};
```

Now, it works, but now (because of the implicit conversions) it is also convertible from `double` and we do not want it:

```
Rational1 r = 2.5; // BUG (will be interpreted as 2.0)
```

I can think of three different ways of preventing it (you have already mentioned 2):

```
struct Rational2
{
    int i_;

    template <typename T>
    Rational2(T i) : i_(i) 
    { static_assert(std::is_same<T, int>::value, "msg"); }
};

struct Rational3
{
    int i_;

    template <typename T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<T, int>::value, int>::type = 0>
    Rational3(T i) : i_(i) {}
};

struct Rational4
{
    int i_;

    Rational4(int i) : i_(i) {}

    template <typename T>
    Rational4(T i) = delete;
};
```

Tests it:

```
Rational2 r = 2.5; // compile-time error
Rational3 r = 2.5; // compile-time error
Rational4 r = 2.5; // compile-time error
```

But, if you check with `std::is_convertible` the result is different:

```
static_assert(std::is_convertible<double, Rational2>::value = true, "");
static_assert(std::is_convertible<double, Rational3>::value = false, "");
static_assert(std::is_convertible<double, Rational4>::value = false, "");
```

This shows that `Rational2` is convertible form `double`: the constructor template is selected and compiled. The standard requires that the `static_assert` inside triggers a compile time error (and with the message of your choosing), but it does not stop the compilation: this is why you see further messages.

Case `Rational3` with `enable_if` makes the template invisible for types other than `int` so, it cannot further check for errors inside the function, but the compiler can look for other constructors, and perhaps select another one.

Case `Rational4` explicitly states that if we try to convert from anything else but `int` it should be treated as hard error: and this is also visible to `std::is_convertible`.

(However you cannot use this technique in your example, where you constrain to a meta-function (`is_integral`) rather than to a concrete type.)

Comment: +1 for implementation of `Rational4`. As you said, it is not a perfect solution to the example I presented in my question, but it actually makes pretty good sense to use this approach in my project.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to let the compiler only specialise for the types you need.

Explaination using example:
Normally you need to make the implementation available to the compiler for all template classes and functions:

```
template<typename T>
class MyClass {
public:
    MyClass(T arg) { d_val = arg; }
privateL
    T d_val;
};
```

So the following will work since the compiler will be able to implement all of them:

```
MyClass<double> classDouble;
MyCalss<int>    classInt;
```

But if you do not provide the implementations then the compiler can't implement them, so you do:

**MyClass.h**

```
template<typename T>
class MyClass {
public:
    MyClass(T arg);
privateL
    T d_val;
};
```

**MyClass.cpp**

```
template<typename T>
MyClass::MyClass() { d_val = arg; }

/* The explicitly make the one for int */
MyClass<int> tmpInt;
```

And to use:

```
MyCalss<int>    classInt;  // Will compile since the compiler already generated the code when it compiled the cpp file
MyClass<double> classDouble; // Wont compile since the compiler does not know how to produce the code.
```

The issue with this approach is that you need to specify each type you want in the source file (cpp).

I use this approach for a templated class for 16 different types. It is a bit of an issue to add new types but it saves me a lot of code to not redo things. It is a very specific problem with a very specific solution.

Comment: +1 for proposing another way (for the sake of thread completeness). I already considered similar approach (actually my thing is implemented like this and I want to get rid of the tone of code it implies), but I don't find it a "good" solution, because you have to either create code for every single integer type, or you have to loose the efficiency.